# An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions when accessing localStorage on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage

Quite strange this one.

I was testing a webpage on IE11 when I suddenly realized that each time that javascript code reaches a call to localStorage it's returning 'An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions' error.

IE ver is 11.09600.17358 on Windows 7 SP1
All IE extensions are currently disabled and I've already tried to empty temporary files and restore IE defaults, also I've checked that DOM storage is enabled, however the problem is still there.

Firefox and Chrome shows no problem executing the app.

I've been googling for a while without success about this one, any insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue until I turned off Protected Mode.  Funnily enough, it's why I couldn't look into Stack Overflow just a couple minutes ago :).